# Can I make that connection?

Tags: database-design

If I have a column with data type `varchar(max)` in a table that contains a big piece of text, can I make a connection between a word or a sentence in that text with another word or a sentence in another column with data type `varchar(max)` in different table?

For example, if I wrote a word in the first column, can I retrieve all sentences that it's mentioned in in another column?

[image]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Comment: Hello Hatem, your question isn't very clear. Could you provide for example two or three sample rows, with sample text, and an example of how you would want to be able to query them? (Doesn't have to be proper SQL, just something so that people can understand exactly what you're trying to do).

Comment: @Mat i will ask a new question with examples

Comment: @Hatem: you should not do that. Edit this one and add the details. There's an "edit" link right under the tags, please use that.

Comment: @Mat is it clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning. This will run badly because of the leading wildcard search in plain SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   T2.BigColumn
FROM
   table1 T1
   JOIN
   table1 T2 ON T2.BigColumn LIKE '%' + T1.KeyWordColumn + '%'
```

If your database engine supports full text search, then this is the way to go.

Comment: +1 Hopefully this is a one time activity to generate a linking table between drugs and the drugs they interact with.

Comment: Maybe an extra warning or two about case-sensitivity (might depend on dbms & collation?) and the fact that that won't match whole words only (i.e. a query for RNA's "technical name" would also find DNA entries - no idea if that's relevant to the domain though).

Comment: @Mat: hopefully comments will be read too. I'm inclined to apply KISS for now...